# My API doesn't show in the explorer and the logs just shows 500

Tags: python, google-cloud-endpoints

As the title indicates my API isn't visible in the explorer and all my logs show is the following:

```
INFO     2013-03-08 13:39:08,182 dev_appserver.py:723] Internal redirection to http://127.0.0.1:8080/_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs
INFO     2013-03-08 13:39:08,198 dev_appserver.py:3104] "GET /_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

The relevant handler from my app.yaml file looks as follows:

```
13 # Endpoint handlers
14 - url: /_ah/spi/.*
15   script: main.app
```

And my code from main.py is as follows:

```
from google.appengine.ext import endpoints
from protorpc import messages

class   Location(messages.Message):
    reg_id = messages.StringField(1)
    phone_number = messages.StringField(2)
    latitude = messages.StringField(3)
    longitude = messages.StringField(4)

@endpoints.api(name='locations', version='v1', description='Location API for where are you app')
class LocationApi(remote.Service):
    @endpoints.method(Location, Location, name='location.insert', path='location', http_method='POST')
    def insert(self, request):
        return request

app = endpoints.api_server([LocationApi])
```

Anyone got a clue about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works now that I list the endpoint handler before the other handlers.

This works:

```
handlers:
# Endpoint handler
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: endpoints.app

# Page handlers
- url: /.*
  script: home.app
```

This doesn't work:

```
handlers:
# Page handlers
- url: /.*
  script: home.app

# Endpoint handler
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: endpoints.app
```

Comment: I observe the same behavior. Seems rather unnatural that handlers must be listed in a certain order. They should at least document it.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following:

1. As you should be able to see from the logs, you're getting an import error. In `main.py` add this

   ```
   from protorpc import remote
   ```
2. From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/endpoints/create_api#allowed-clients-and-audiences):

   > **Note:** If you want to test authenticated calls to your API using the Google API Explorer, you must also supply its client ID, which is available through the Endpoints library as `endpoints.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID`.
3. Check your logs again to make sure the code actually runs. You're getting a 500 because of a Python exception being raise and there may be other issues with your code, though it doesn't seem like from what you've posted.

Comment: I've already added the import of remote to my actual code. But that was indeed missing.

Comment: I've genenrated the api using the following command: "endpointscfg.py get_client_lib java -o . -f rest main.LocationApi" Which ran without errors. I also uploaded it to http://whereareyoudroid.appspot.com ... still nothing

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your python file can't find the import for:

```
from protorpc import remote
```

Therefore use the terminal, skip the GUI, navigate to the appengine sdk directory and put your project in there. For mac it is:

```
/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/
```